# Subtraction of Variable Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application where a user is setting a target number people to receive an issue of a magazine, I'm able to calculate how many people they have signed up for the issue via the Split, and I'm trying to calculate the difference so they can see how many more people they need to add to reach their target.

Here is my split model:

```
class Split < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :issue
    has_and_belongs_to_many :geographies 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :media 


    @total_selected = Split.sum(:quantity)
    @balance = @Split.issue.target - @total_selected

end
```

I'm getting a "undefined method `issue'" error message.

Here is my Splits Controller with the change that was recommended.:

```
class SplitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_split, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /splits
  # GET /splits.json
  def index
    @splits = Split.all
    @chosen_splits = Issue.find(1).splits
    @balance = split.balance
  end
```

I made the changes to the model that were recommended. Now I'm getting an error that says "undefined local variable or method `split'"

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `issue` as an instance variable. Put it in a method to access it.

```
class Split < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :issue
    has_and_belongs_to_many :geographies 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :media 

    def balance
        issue.target - Split.sum(:quantity)
    end
end
```

To add the balance to your views, query the split you want, add this to the action in your controller:

```
@balance = split.balance
```

Then in your view do this:

```
<%= @balance %>
```

Comment: This got the error to go away which is good. But, when I put <%= @Balance %> into my Split index view nothing appears.

Comment: see edits for how to access that data in your views.